# Trait function that takes a closure which takes a lifetime GAT: why does the lifetime "not appear in the trait input types?"

Tags: rust, generic-associated-types

```
trait Example {
    type HasLifetime<'a>;

    fn example<F>()
    where
        F: for<'a> FnOnce(Self::HasLifetime<'a>) -> Box<dyn 'a + Send>;
}
```

Produces:

```
error[E0582]: binding for associated type `Output` references lifetime `'a`, which does not appear in the trait input types
 --> src/lib.rs:6:53
  |
6 |         F: for<'a> FnOnce(Self::HasLifetime<'a>) -> Box<dyn 'a + Send>;
  |                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm a bit confused how the lifetime "does not appear in the input types" as it quite clearly does.  The following changes allow the code to compile:

- Changing the closure argument type to `&'a Self::HasLifetime<'a>`.
- Changing the closure argument type to `Foo<'a>` given the existence of a `struct Foo<'a>`.

Why is the lifetime GAT case rejected, given that it also takes the lifetime parameter as an input?

Comment: This sounds related to [issue 86702](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86702)

Answer (score 0):

Take for example the following implementation:

```rust
impl Example for Something {
    type HasLifetime<'a> = ();

    // ...
}
```

In which `example()` normalizes too:

```rust
fn example<F>()
where
    F: for<'a> FnOnce(()) -> Box<dyn 'a + Send>;
```

Closures (and traits with associated types in general) when an associated type references some lifetime not in the trait's generic parameters or the implementing type, are rejected for soundness reasons. So this cannot work.

If you change it to `&'a Self::HasLifetime<'a>` or `Foo<'a>`, the parameter always references the lifetime (even if the associated type doesn't), so this works again.

Comment: It's not clear to me why this example would be unsound. Since no references are captured, `'a` could be safely replaced with _any_ lifetime (including `'static`), no? What's an example where this would actually cause a soundness problem?

Comment: @cdhowie I _believe_ that I read that this is not unsound per se, just the current working of the compiler makes this unsound. Let me see if I can find anything...

Comment: @cdhowie This is basically [RFC 447](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0447-no-unused-impl-parameters.md). It doesn't explain a lot why this is unsound, though.

Comment: @cdhowie See also [issue #32330](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32330), which demonstrates the unsoundness. Basically, based on local needs we may project the associated type with different lifetime each time, and this leads to unsoundness where they are not equal.

Comment: So, basically, the answer is "it's a limitation in the compiler but later it could be made to work?"

Comment: @cdhowie I don't know if it'll ever made to work. I don't think there is enough motivation, and I'm even not sure that my understanding that this limitation could be lifted is correct.